# Flutter: memory leak with isolate (compute)

Tags: flutter, memory-leaks, dart-isolates

I see memory leak every time I call compute() in my Flutter app, which is basically just a convenient way to spawn an isolate as far as I understand. My app memory footprint grows and never goes down after GC.
I've reduced my code to just calling an empty function - and the issue is still reproducible:

```
  // run my _encodeJpeg in isolate
  await compute(_encodeJpeg, null);


  Future<void> _encodeJpeg(_JpegEncodeParams params) async {
    // I've made this function empty just to see if the memory leak is still reproducible - yes it is!
  }
```

Note that if I don't call compute() - there is no memory leak in my app. So it is definitely compute() that causes the issue.

**Then I've created a new starter Flutter app (default one with button and counter) - and call compute() from that app the same way and it works fine! No memory leaks. Weird, right?!**

There is something in my app that causes memory leak on compute(), while the app itself (if I don't call compute) doesn't have any memory leaks. I've created my app using some of the previous versions of Flutter, but now I compile it using the latest Flutter (see below).

**Could there be something in my app that needs to be updated manually to make compute() work as expected?**

UPDATE: I don't see this issue using library such as Computer (https://pub.dev/packages/computer):

```
final computer = Computer();
await computer.turnOn(workersCount: 1);
await computer.compute<void, _JpegEncodeParams>(_encodeTempJpeg, param: ...);
computer.turnOff();
```

flutter doctor:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1256], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 1.22.5 at C:\sdk\flutter
• Framework revision 7891006 (6 weeks ago), 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
• Engine revision ae90085a84
• Dart version 2.10.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I see the same issue on flutter 2.2.3

All `data` I pass as argument to the compute are kept in memory - `await compute(exampleGlobalFunction, data)`.

I checked it in `Flutter DevTools` / `Memory` tab and the instances of data are never released. If I call the function directly (without compute) then data are properly released.

EDIT: I think I found the solution - created a github issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/86470